How to install ruby and gem (one_gadget) in WSL [ERROR]
I want to download ruby and install one_gadget extension with gem for Pwnable. But I don't know why I can't install ruby in WSL.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-lato libgmp-dev libgmpxx4ldbl libruby3.0 rake ri ruby ruby-dev ruby-net-telnet ruby-rubygems ruby-webrick ruby-xmlrpc ruby3.0 ruby3.0-dev ruby3.0-doc
  rubygems-integration unzip zip
Suggested packages:
  gmp-doc libgmp10-doc libmpfr-dev bundler
E: Sub-process [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true returned an error code (100)
E: Failure running hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true
E: Sub-process [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true returned an error code (100)
E: Failure running hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true

Or is there other way to download "one_gadget" (https://github.com/david942j/one_gadget) extension?
sudo apt install ruby -> that's what I tried.
# sudo apt install ruby
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-lato libruby3.0 rake ruby-net-telnet ruby-rubygems ruby-webrick ruby-xmlrpc ruby3.0 rubygems-integration unzip zip
Suggested packages:
  ri ruby-dev bundler
E: Sub-process [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true returned an error code (100)
E: Failure running hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true
E: Sub-process [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true returned an error code (100)
E: Failure running hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true` -> Error Message


I would highly recommend a version manager rather than trying to install ruby directly. Options include: rvm, rbenv, asdf, chruby, etc.

Which WSL are you using (Suse, Debian, Ubuntu, Alpine)?
